# Call to a member function consultarprestamos() on a non-object

Tags: php

Esta es la clase y dentro de ella tengo la función `ConsultarPrestamos`:

```
class bibliotecaCliente{

public $PUBLICMYSQL;
function bibliotecaCliente(){
    $this->PUBLICMYSQL = new CONMYSQL;
    $this->PUBLICMYSQL->conectar();

}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes comentar lo que intentas hacer? Creo que no estás comenzando con buen pie, por lo que se aprecia en tu código. Saludos.

Comment: Quiero mostrar datos en una tabla recorriendolo con foreach pero marca este error;  Cannot use object of type CONMYSQL as array in en esta linea; if (strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $prestamo['fecha_devolucion'])) < strtotime("today GMT")) {                             
                        $fila='<tr class="retrasado">';
                   }

Comment: Por eso digo que no has empezado con buen pie, tienes problemas con tus   objetos, por ejemplo aquí: `$this->PUBLICMYSQL = new CONMYSQL;` el new no se llama así, sino `new $objeto ();` y a veces dentro de los paréntesis van parámetros que se le pasan al constructor de la clase. Claro, debe existir una clase que se llame `CONMYSQL` sería importante que leas algo sobre la convención de nombres, no es crítico pero es importante usarla para la comprensión de los programas. Sería bueno que leas esto: http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.php antes de seguir. Saludos,

Comment: Si tengo una clase que se llama CONMYSQL, gracias Cedano :D

Comment: @ALEX, te recomiendo **[edit] tu pregunta**. Los comentarios son temporales.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo, estás inicializando mal tu clase:

```
$prestamos = new bibliotecaCliente();
// Te faltó añadir los dos parentesis
```

Luego, la variable `$bibliotecaCliente` no está inizializada en ningún lado, por eso debes acceder al método `consultarprestamos();` mediante `$prestamos` que es la instancia creada anteriormente

```
$prestamos->consultarprestamos();
```

Comment: $prestamos = new bibliotecaCliente();  
                  $prestamos->consultarprestamos(); ¿así?

Comment: Si, así debería ser

Answer (score -1):

Intenta así para llamar al método:

```
$prestamos->consultarprestamos();
```

Comment: Ahora me marca ese error; Fatal error: Cannot use object of type CONMYSQL as array in. Tengo una clase que se llama CONMYSQL es la conexión a la BD

Comment: edita tu pregunta poniendo este nuevo error, y de paso incluye la clase bibliotecaCliente

Comment: Amenadiel ya edite

Comment: Juan, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
**[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Una vez que tengas 50 puntos de reputación podrás [hacer comentarios](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).